# What is the cause of Error Code 118, and how can I resolve this?

Tags: steam

[image: error]

Above is a screenshot of the error I am getting in my Steam application. It says:

> "Unable to connect to server. Server may be offline or you may not be connected to the internet."

I have a connection to the internet and it's working properly, I have no clue what might be the cause of this problem but I can visit the site when I use the "cache" option instead as below;

[image: some image]

Any idea what might be the fix for this?

Comment: What happens if you try and access Steam's website without using the cache link?

Comment: it doesnt load, it only shows 'This webpage is not available'

Comment: When you use that link, you are actually looking at a cached copy of the site on Google's servers - not the actual site.

Answer (score 10):

Steam's servers are most likely down.  This happens sometimes during heavy traffic, but oftentimes it's during a steam sale like the Autumn sale they had in November or the Holiday sale they are having now.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a summary of Valve's advice, taken from the [Troubleshooting](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1456-EUDN-2493) part of their help page:

1. Check your firewalls:  Your firewalls could be disabling portions of Steam's service
2. Disable background applications: These could be interfering with Steam
3. Virus, spyware, malware, etc.:  These could be interfering with Steam
4. Check your router: This could be the main source of the problem.

More or less, if the above solutions don't work for you, this is likely a problem on Steam's end, so just take it easy and wait for Steam servers to go back to normal.

Comment: how would i know if firewall is blocking steam?
my virus is already disabled and router is good

Comment: Scan your computer for viruses.

Comment: I don't know what firewall you're using, but if it's Windows Firewall: Control Panel -> Windows Firewall -> Allow a program or feature through the firewall. Check if Steam is there.